# how does government binding theory account for verbs taking bare form in a subjunctives

Tags: subjunctive, government-and-binding

In "he demanded that you be silent"
How does the gb theory accounts for the bare form of the verb "be" ?

Comment: Government and binding theory isn't my specialty, but wouldn't it just be selected by "that"?

Comment: Only in the scope of certain verbs (or whatever they're called now).

Comment: see e.g. Liliane Haegeman 1986 *The present subjunctive in contemporary British English* (you can easily find it online) - if you are interested in GB, then you should know who she is

Comment: @Alex B. Liliane proposes 1) the infl node of the subjunctive has unspecified T and M (tense and modal).  2) when the subjunctives occur as a dependent clauses, the infl of the matrix clause "controls" the infl of subjunctive clauses. This is very new to me as the concept of "control" as i learned it was only shown for "subject control". It seems Liliane has generalised this to infl node as well. Thank you so much Alex, your source is very on point. I will have to see papers that cited this paper to see what others have said about this proposal.